# sql server 2 views in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have 3 Different Views

1. `select count(*) as Grandtotal from table x where id=1`
2. `select count(*) as total from table x where id=1 and [bla bla] Group by id`
3. `select top1(a) from table y`

i need to create view that will contain the flowing column

GrandTotal, total , a

Comment: Why is count(*) the only field in the SELECT statement of a "view"? And aren't there 3 "views" there? Can we assume that by "view" you mean "selection criteria"?

Comment: select count(*) as total from table x where id=1 and [bla bla] Group by id ==> you don't need the GROUP BY clause as you'll only have id=1 there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS GrandTotal,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN [bla bla] THEN 1 END) AS Total
  (SELECT TOP 1 a FROM y) AS a
FROM x
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `case`, you can also combine the selects in a single query:

```
select  sum(case when id=1 then 1 end) as Id1GrandTotal
,       count(distinct case when id=1 and [bla bla] then id end) 
            as Id1AndBlahBlahExists
,       max(a) as TopValueOFA
from    TableY
```

Comment: There are two tables mentioned in the original post, `x` and `y`.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't imagine it to be that easy: catch a flaw in someone's answer, and that person will vote for yours! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 (SELECT Count(*) FROM table x WHERE id = 1) AS GrandTotal,
 (SELECT Count(*) FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND ...) AS Total,
 (SELECT TOP 1 fieldname FROM table ...) AS a
```

should work, but you may have to join to a dummy table to get some info on some databases to

e.g.

```
SELECT 
 ...
FROM numbers_table n WHERE n.num = 1
```

Comment: Do you have any relation between tables X and Y in your example?
Please post that, you might not need a dummy table.